# HX711 zero factor

Tags: microcontroller, analog, measurement, load-cell, logic-analyzer

[image]

I have three load cells (YZC-1B). These load cells' capacity is 50 kg. I guess I use Bogde's HX711 library.

In monitor, the zero factor for the first two load cells is 8,000,000, but for the last load cell the zero factor is 40,000. When I swap the green and white wires (swap A- and A+), the zero factor is again 8,000,000, but the last zero factors (8 million) are negative and my load results have got a negative value.

When I look at the logic analyzer, I took 000000010110100111011010 converted to decimal, the result is 92634. My zero factor is -46377 (in -46377 load results look good).

Question 1, `long zero_factor = scale.read_average();` in the library; why are these zero factors always split in two?

Question 2, Why do zero factors' values have negative values?

Question 3, Why is the last load cell's zero factor -46377?

[image]

Comment: This version of HX711 library for Arduino? https://github.com/bogde/HX711.

Comment: @tlfong01 yes for arduino.

Comment: (1) YZC-1B has a max capacity of only 40kg: https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32225995715.html. (2) Please give exact specific links to your (a) library and (b) load cell.

Comment: (3) You might like to give us links to the references and tutorials you have been following. My references: (4) Why Is It Important To Calibrate Load Cell And Torque Sensors? - Futek
https://www.futek.com/load-cell-calibration-services

(5) tlfong01's HX711 Testing and Calibration Results - 2019jan23
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1420380&hilit=hx711+tlfong01#p1420380

(6) Rpi.com Forum Search "hx711 tlfong01" found 62 matches:
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/search.php?keywords=hx711+tlfong01&sid=37c74a2a6c35f73a9ea83db3a3b521f0

Comment: You might like to give me a diagram or a photo of your Wheatstone or other bridge setup, likw this: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1395217&hilit=hx711+tlfong01#p1395585

Comment: @tlfong01 thank u for ur comment. My load cells datasheet here says 40 or 50kg capacity. https://www.ardu.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Vejecelle-YZC-1B.pdf. I use bogde's library. I got a reference from this link; https://www.electroniclinic.com/arduino-hx711-and-load-cell-weight-measurement-and-calibration/

Comment: (1) Your electroniclinic.com tutorial uses a 1kg load cell, but your load cell is 50kg, which makes calibration a bit difficult.  You see that I only experimented with load from 100g to 1kg, and I used standard weights to do the calibration. (2) I see the tutorial is a set of three tutorials, from Arduino to ESP8266 and ESP32 with WiFi one, and you are following the last, most complicated one.

Comment: (3) As you see that HX711 is just an ADC with high precision of 24 bits. This means that the input is simply an analogue voltage with a small value. That is why we need the Wheatsone bridge to sort of amplify many many times, to higher, say 0~3V3 by . (4) So you see I did the calibration is two big steps: (a) offline, annually, without the HX711, but only use a multi-meter. This is to make sure that you can calibrated the zero load point with no load, and half loading, and full loading, at half and full scale of the analog voltage range, 0 ~ 3V3.

Comment: (b) then do the calibration using HX711, or even better with a simple SPI ADC such as MCP3008, though with a very rough 12-bit resolution. This is sort of proof of concept, of the Wheatstone bridge thing. (5) You might also like to forget the strain gauge for now, and use a cheapy pressure sensitive sensor to learn the basic concepts.

Comment: (6) And if you are using Arduino, you can use its built in 12-bit ADC to measure the output of the Wheatstone bridge, with very low resolution, but only to prove concept, before trying HX711.

Comment: (1) my calibration factor is different for each load cells. For example; 1kg load cell's calibration factor is 217, 50kg load cell's calibration factor is 45-43. (4) how can I use a multimeter for calibration idk, can you share a link about that?  I couldn't get why I must use less bit ADC .

Comment: I see.  So you have three load cells, 50kg, 50kg, and 1kg. (1) I would suggest you to put the 50kg load cell aside, and ***TEST ONLY the 1KG LOAD CELL***. (2) I would suggest you to put the HX711 aside, and ***use an Arduino (or Pico) built in 12-bit ADC to test the output of the 1kg load cell connected Wheatstone bridge***.

Comment: I see.  So you have three load cells, 50kg, 50kg, and 1kg. (1) I would suggest you to put the 50kg load cell aside, and ***TEST ONLY the 1KG LOAD CELL***. (2) I would suggest you to put the HX711 aside, and ***use an Arduino (or Pico) built in 12-bit ADC to test the output of the 1kg load cell connected Wheatstone bridge***. (3) I have listed a couple of references on how I did my research on load cell, bridge, and use a multi-meter.  You might like to skim my experiments and see if you understand what I have been doing. (4) Do you have any experience in using (a) a multimeter, (b) scope?